# Checking For user input between certain limit if not asking again until correct input is entered

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, user-input

My program compiles correctly but i am having problem when i run it. The first scanf (width) works correctly but when i try with another scanf(height) i get **segmentation fault 11.** 
And can i do this program to work **without using pointers**. (Also i need limit checker function because i have to use it again and again in my program).

```
#include <stdio.h>
void limitChecker(int x, int y, int* input);
int main(void)
{
    int* x;
    int* y;
    printf("Enter the width of the windows. (3 - 5) : ");
    scanf("%d", x);
    limitChecker(3, 5, x);
    printf("width: %d \n", *x);
    printf("Enter the height of the windows. (2 - 4) : ");
    scanf("%d", y);
    limitChecker(2, 4, y);
    printf("Height: %d \n", *y);

}

void limitChecker(int x, int y, int* input)
{
    while(!(*input>=x && *input<=y))
    {
    printf("Please enter a value between (%d - %d): ",x,y);
    scanf("%d", input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a reference to the variables used in the scanf().

For example, `scanf("%d", &x);`

The first parameter of `scanf()` is for the type of data, and the following parameter(s) are a list of pointers to where you would like the user input to be stored.

CORRECTED CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void limitChecker(int x, int y, int* input);
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    printf("Enter the width of the windows. (3 - 5) : ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    limitChecker(3, 5, &x);
    printf("width: %d \n", x);
    printf("Enter the height of the windows. (2 - 4) : ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    limitChecker(2, 4, &y);
    printf("Height: %d \n", y);

}

void limitChecker(int x, int y, int* input)
{
    while(!(*input>=x && *input<=y))
    {
    printf("Please enter a value between (%d - %d): ",x,y);
    scanf("%d", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant because its an pointer (if i add & i get error during compilation) This is my error "format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’"

Comment: Okay, I see. You simply made `x` and `y` pointers, when you should actually declare them `int x, y;`.

Comment: ya i know they are variables. I am having problem with the input which is pointer (You are getting confused because i use same name x and x in my function as well as main)

Comment: Your variables are only for pointers, not for actual integers, therefore you would need to manually allocate space using `malloc()`, or you can simply just declare them as the actual `int` variables and get their pointers on the fly using `&x` and `&y`.

Comment: i tried using variable but the real value does not change due to scope .

Comment: @Nakib I have revised your code to work as you would have expected it to. Do you understand where you went wrong? Please select an answer so others with the same issue will be helped.

Comment: Thanks man it worked. I am new to c programming and i didn't know we can pass variable as poniter.

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate memory to hold `x` and `y`.

Allocate them on the stack and then use the `&` address of operator to obtain a pointer to that memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int limitChecker(int x, int y, int input);
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    printf("Enter the width of the windows. (3 - 5) : ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    x = limitChecker(3, 5, x);
    printf("width: %d \n", x);
    printf("Enter the height of the windows. (2 - 4) : ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    y = limitChecker(2, 4, y);
    printf("Height: %d \n", y);

}

int limitChecker(int x, int y, int input)
{
    while(!(input>=x && input<=y))
    {
    printf("Please enter a value between (%d - %d): ",x,y);
    scanf("%d", &input);
    }

    return input;
}
```

If you want `x` and `y` to be pointers then you have to assign them valid memory before you use them.

```
int * x = malloc(sizeof(int));
int * y = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @Nakib Then you need to allocate memory to hold your actual `int`.  An `int *` does not come with valid memory to hold the contents by default. Edited.

Comment: @Nakib my bad. Edited the limit function too now. You need to have it return the new value then if no pointer is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int limitChecker(int x, int y, int value){
    return x <= value && value <= y;
}

int inputInt(void){
    //x >= 0
    int x = 0;
    int ch;
    while('\n'!=(ch=getchar())){
        if('0'<=ch && ch <= '9')
            x = x * 10 + (ch - '0');
        else 
            break;
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void){
    int x, y;
    do{
        printf("Enter the width of the windows. (3 - 5) : ");
        x = inputInt();
    }while(!limitChecker(3, 5, x));
    printf("width: %d \n", x);
    do{
        printf("Enter the height of the windows. (2 - 4) : ");
        y = inputInt();
    }while(!limitChecker(2, 4, y));
    printf("Height: %d \n", y);
    return 0;
}
```